# Pseudo Differential Operator example

Tags: operator-theory, pseudo-differential-operators

I was reading a introduction about Pseudo differential operators, and the definition of that type of operator was:

$$|\partial_x^\alpha \partial_\xi^\beta f(x,\xi) | \le C_{\alpha,\beta}(1 + |\xi|)^{n-|\alpha|}$$ where $x,\xi$ $\in$ $\!R^m\times\!R^p$ ,$C_{\alpha,\beta}$ is a constant that depends only on $\alpha$ and $\beta$ , n is the order of the Pseudo differential operator $f(x,\xi)$.I was trying to prove that $\lt \xi\gt = (1 + |\xi|^2)^{m/2}$  is a Pseudo differential operator, the hint was to use the fact that  $f(a,x)=(a^2 + |\xi|^2)^{m/2}$ have the homogeneity property, that is $f(ra,r\xi)=r^mf(a,\xi)$ but i was not able to prove using that.$$ $$
$\alpha=(\alpha_1,..,\alpha_m) \quad \partial_x^\alpha f(x)=\partial_{x_1}^{\alpha_1}...\partial_{x_m}^{\alpha_m}f(x) \quad |\alpha|= |\alpha_1| +....+ |\alpha_m| $

Comment: Do you mean $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^m$ rather than $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^M$?  Also $(1+|\xi|^2)^{m/2}$ instead of $\sqrt[\frac{m}2]{1+|\xi|^2}$?

Comment: I put M to distinguish from m, and $(1 + |\xi|^2)^{\frac{m}{2}} = \sqrt[\frac{m}{2}]{1 + |\xi|^2}$

Comment: But $\sqrt[\frac{m}{2}]{\quad}$ is taking the (m/2)-th root is raising to power (2/m), not taking (m/2)-th power.  Also, the symbol $\xi_i=\sigma(\partial_i)$ is like a cotangent vector so there must be the same $m$.  Using a different $M$ is just confusing.

Comment: You are right sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f(x,\xi)=\langle\xi\rangle=(1+|\xi|^2)^{m/2}$ does not depend on $x$, so you only need to prove it for $\alpha=0$.
Note that each time you do a $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\xi_j}$ on $\xi^\gamma(1+|\xi|^2)^k$ one of two things happen

- you killed one of the $\xi_j$ occuring in $\xi^\gamma$ and so $|\gamma|$ goes down by $1$.
- you operate on the $(1+|\xi|^2)^k$ factor, gaining a factor $2k\xi_j(1+|\xi|^2)^{-1}$, so $|\gamma|$ goes up by $1$ but the power of $(1+|\xi|^2)$ goes down by $1$

So the upshot is, after you apply $\partial_\xi^\beta$ to $f$, the result is a sum of terms $c_\gamma\xi^\gamma(1+|\xi|^2)^{\leq \frac{m}{2}-|\gamma|}$ with $|\gamma|\leq|\beta|$.  Furthermore, you can bound the coefficient $|c_\gamma|\leq C(\beta,m)$ and of course the bound $|\xi|<(1+|\xi|^2)^{1/2}\leq 1+|\xi|$, so that gives the bound
$$
|\partial_\xi^\beta f|\leq C_\beta (1+|\xi|^2)^{\frac{m}{2}} \leq C_\beta (1+|\xi|)^m
$$